When install jupyterhub, many other files installed
Hi I just installed jupyterhub using conda install jupyterhub
However It not work until I installed notebook.
I noticed when I install jupyterhub, it has some other component installed, like jupyterhub-singleuser, jupyter-kernel,jupyter-lab,jupyter-notebook,jupyter-server,etc.
My question is:
1 what are those components used for? I just want a jupyterhub service.
2 since it has already installed jupyter-lab, jupyter-notebook, why I still need to install notebook package to complete the pieces.
I mean it provide a lot of service but didn't provide the essential needed package.

"I just want a jupyterhub service." Have you looked into using The Littlest JupyterHub? See 'When to use The Littlest JupyterHub
' where it says, it "is an opinionated and pre-configured distribution to deploy a JupyterHub on a single machine (in the cloud or on your own hardware). It is designed to be a more lightweight and maintainable solution for use-cases where size, scalability, and cost-savings are not a huge concern." That seems to address concerns since it is lightweight. "1 what are those components used for?" For ...

 everything in that list looking over the architecture page of the Jupyter Documentation should give you a good sense of how the parts you list play together. As for 'why I still need to install notebook package to complete the pieces', it is hard to say because your supplied command doesn't tell us much. What channel did you install from? You probably wanted conda install conda-forge::jupyterhubif you aren't going with the TLJH or 'Zero to JupyterHub with Kubernetes' guides.

 Plus this guide to JupyterHub recommended here on the Jupyter Community Discourse Page. Or see the motivation section here announcing the JupyterHub Outpost to get a better sense of the complexity and more details on the architecture from a current view.

@Wayne Sir, thank you very much for the very detailed explanation and documentation, and I will look them through; I think you can put the reply into an answer so you don't need to be limited on the characters. Just a suggestion, if you think this way is better, never mind~~ :)

Good idea. I have made an answer with the arrangement a little better.

"I just want a jupyterhub service."
Have you looked into using The Littlest JupyterHub? See 'When to use The Littlest JupyterHub ' where it says, it "is an opinionated and pre-configured distribution to deploy a JupyterHub on a single machine (in the cloud or on your own hardware). It is designed to be a more lightweight and maintainable solution for use-cases where size, scalability, and cost-savings are not a huge concern." That may address your concerns better since it is lightweight.
"1 what are those components used for?"
For  everything in that list looking over the architecture page of the Jupyter Documentation should give you a good sense of how the parts you list play together.
Additional resources on the architecture and how things work together:
This guide to JupyterHub recommended here on the Jupyter Community Discourse Page.
Or see the motivation section here announcing the JupyterHub Outpost to get a better sense of the complexity and more details on the architecture from a current view.
As for 'why I still need to install notebook package to complete the pieces', it is hard to say because your supplied command doesn't tell us much. What channel did you install from?
You probably wanted conda install conda-forge::jupyterhubif you aren't going with the TLJH or 'Zero to JupyterHub with Kubernetes' guides.
